# Why does autonum fail to number and label a referenced equation in a split environment?

Tags: cross-referencing, autonum

Here's my MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{autonum}
\begin{document}
References to equations \ref{1} and \ref{2} and \ref{3}.
\begin{equation}
\label{1}
\begin{split}
\textrm{(1) This equation is correctly numbered because it is referenced.}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
%\label{2}
\begin{split}
\label{2}
\textrm{(2) This one is not numbered (incorrectly), although it is referenced.}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{3}
\textrm{(3) This one is to illustrate that equation counters are incorrect.}
\end{equation}
\begin{equation}
\label{4}
\textrm{This one is not numbered correctly, because it is not referenced.}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

You will see that the second equation is not labeled (incorrectly), although it is referenced by the number "2". Also, the number of the third equation is also "2" (incorrectly as well).

I found that a workaround is to write

```
\begin{equation}
\label{...}
\begin{split}
```

instead of

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
\label{...}
```

However, I failed to find anything in the `autonum` documentation that this is required. Also, there is no warning, so in a long document, this mistake may easily go unnoticed. Is this a bug in `autonum` or did I miss something elementary to Latex here?

Comment: you need to have `\usepackage{amsmath}` for this to compile.

Comment: No, I don't. My MWE compiles as is on a current MikTex 2.9. From the `autonum` documentation, section 3.1: "Normally, amsmath is loaded automatically to make use of the more advanced math environments."

Comment: okay -- when i first tested this, i was compiling under tex live 2012, and that version of `autonum` did *not* load `amsmath`.  the newer version (2014/04/04) does load it.  i've done further testing, and report the findings in an answer below.

Comment: Placing the label outside the `split` environment seems more natural.

Answer (score 5):

testing with the current version of `autonum` shows that when a `\label` is inside
the `split` environment, `autonum` doesn't recognize it.  further testing shows that `autonum` correctly numbers equations within `align`.

however, substituting `aligned` for `split` in your example, the numbering fails in
the same way.

it appears that `autonum` fails to recognize a label if it is inside an "inner level"
environment.

since the `\label` is recognized in either position when only `amsmath` is loaded,
i consider this a problem with `autonum`, and the author should be notified.

Comment: Thanks for the analysis. It will be fixed in version 0.3.11, soon.

Comment: @PatrickHäcker do you know whether this has been fixed yet?

Comment: @PatrickHäcker I believe this hasn't been fixed yet?